# unit vectors: solving with component method and graphical method

Tags: physics

P and Q are vectors in the X , Y plane, have the same magnitude, and are perpendicular to each other. If Q=3.0i+4.0j. What is P?

Comment: Generally, posting questions without showing what you have tried will get your question downvoted. Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: I cant really figure it out because if they are perpendicular to each other why is it they are only in X, Y plane. ?

Comment: There are infintely many answers because there are two directions that are perpendicular to $Q$ in the plane. Hint: let $P = ai + bj$ and solve $P \circ Q = 0$

Comment: I dont know if this is right. My answer is P= -4.0 i + 3.0 j or P= 4.0 i - 3.0 j ?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this is right. My answer is P= -4.0 i + 3.0 j or P= 4.0 i - 3.0 j ?

Comment: Yes, that's them. You might as well answer your own question.